# Saving a array on a column Text Type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After trying to save a record on php tinker im getting a error

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'PHP error:  Array to string conversion ...vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection.php on line 80
```

Is complaning because of my array on the "options" property, what im doing wrong?

My record:

```
=> App\Question {#690
         survey_id: 1,
         label: "what services need",
         input_type: "checkbox",
         required: true,
         options: [
           "Tlevision",
           "Internet ",
           "Phone",
           "Mobile",
         ],
         order: 1,
         updated_at: "2017-02-01 17:34:28",
         created_at: "2017-02-01 17:34:28",
       }
```

In Tinker basically in the option field i used:

$info->options = ["title 1", "title 2"..]

Comment: Need more information.  What are you typing into tinker?

Comment: you have to either  serialize or json encode that array and then try to save it

Comment: @MMMTroy i updated my question

Comment: Okay.  So are you intending to save those options to your database then?  @Anant is correct then.  You can't save an array to a database.  You either need to make a relationship or save it as json, which to the database is simply a string.  Quick fix would be to say $info->options = json_encode(["title 1", "title 2"..]);

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

I guess the best option is to use [casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array',
];
```

> Once the cast is defined, you may access the options attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When you set the value of the options attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage.

**Option 2**

Create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to automatically serialize and a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to unserialize the data.

**Option 3**

Manually serialize `options`, like:

```
Model::create([
    ....
    'options' => json_encode($options),
    'order' => 1
]);
```

And when you get this property from DB, unserialize it manually:

```
$options = json_decode($result->options, true);
```